# Is it possible to customize Find Bar / Search Result Screen in Magnolia Admin Central?

Tags: magnolia

In Magnolia, is it feasible to customize Find Bar UI or Search Result Screen to add an "Export" button so that users could export search results to CSV?

I realized that Find Bar UI component is a core component that belongs to admincentral module. If we wanted to extend it then we might have to touch to Magnolia core features. I'm wondering whether there is any possible approach.

[Export button can be placed wherever in this search result screen like below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqxZz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible/feasible? Yes, you need to customize the UI and then reconfigure the setup to use your customized Findbar component instead of the default one (see [this](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/MODULES/repos/admincentral/browse/magnolia-admincentral/src/main/resources/META-INF/magnolia/admincentral.xml)). But since [the code is open source](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/MODULES/repos/admincentral/browse/magnolia-admincentral/src/main/java/info/magnolia/admincentral/findbar), it shouldn't be a problem.